# MySQL: After inserting data into a table, the table remains empty

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

i'm trying to run this simple query:

```
insert into diff_set_values(value)
select value 
from diff_sets
group by value;
```

but after it is finished, there is no data in the destination table `diff_set_values`. Unfortunately, there's so much data in the source table `diff_sets`, that the query runs a little more than an hour. Too long for MySQL Workbench to keep the connection to the MySQL server. It says "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query" after 30 seconds, but doesn't tell me if any other error occured.

**information about the tables and server**

The source table `diff_sets` contains about 186 million records with 4 columns (`ID1 int`, `ID2 int`, `diffType int`, `value varchar(64)`). Primary Key: ID1, ID2, diffType. The column `value` also has an index `idx_diff_sets_value`.

Example data:

```
ID1     ID2     diffType  value
25151   24978   15        13ddfb5fa96ffebffbdfd3ff7dd7cabd7
66675   66670   14        13ddfb5fbb5cdefe7bffffbd359775ffe
66701   66675   18        13ddfb5fbb5cdefe7bffffbd359775ffe
25789   25750   14        13ddfb5fbf7fdeff7fabff3edbfcefadf
25789   25778   17        13ddfb5fbf7fdeff7fabff3edbfcefadf
```

The destination table `diff_set_values` is empty and contains a column `value varchar(64)` and 6 other int columns that will be filled with null. Those columns will be updated later.

I'm running MySQL Community Server 8.0.16 on my Notebook. I'm accessing it with MySQL Workbench 8.0 and I have exclusive access to the database.

**What I tried**

I've created a stored procedure and inserted all error handlers I could think of.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fillInterDiffSets`()
BEGIN
    declare continue handler for sqlexception
    begin
        get diagnostics condition 1 @p1 = returned_sqlstate, @p2 = message_text;
        insert into sp_error(error_code, error_description, error_time)
        select @p1, @p2, now();
    end;
    
    declare continue handler for sqlwarning
    begin
        get diagnostics condition 1 @p1 = returned_sqlstate, @p2 = message_text;
        insert into sp_error(error_code, error_description, error_time)
        select @p1, @p2, now();
    end;

    declare continue handler for not found
    begin
        get diagnostics condition 1 @p1 = returned_sqlstate, @p2 = message_text;
        insert into sp_error(error_code, error_description, error_time)
        select @p1, @p2, now();
    end;
    
    insert into diff_set_values(value)
    select value 
    from diff_sets
    group by value;
END
```

When I run that procedure, I can watch the size of the diff_set_values.ibd file increasing. After a bit more than an hour the increasing stops at about 5.2 GiB. When I run `show processlist`, the process is still active for a few minutes.

When the process disappears from the `show processlist`, there are no records in the `diff_set_values` table and yet no error messages in the `sp_errors` table.

I tried, if the error handlers work by removing the `group by` part of the query, which immediately results in a "duplicate key" message in the `sp errors` table.

I tried to use `select distinct value from diff_sets` instead of `select value from diff_sets group by value`. Doesn't help.

I tried `select sql_big_result distinct value from diff_sets`. The only difference is that the file size of the ibd file doesn't increase and `show processlist` only tells me "creating sort index", but eventually disappears from the processlist.

I limited the query by appending `limit 0, 1000000` to it. That works as expected.

A few months ago, the `diff_sets` table was smaller and the query worked properly.

I'm running out of ideas what to do. Is there a way to see all errors that occured on the server? Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: One possible cause is that the tx runs out of log space. What is the value of: innodb_log_file_size ?

Comment: That's 50331648. The innodb_log_buffer_size is 16777216.

Comment: Looks like non-commited transaction. Destination table is empty initially - monitor table's file size during insert..

Comment: *Too long for MySQL Workbench to keep the connection to the MySQL server. It says "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query" after 30 seconds, but doesn't tell me if any other error occured* - lost connection means that you will not receive messages occured after, both success and error ones. Try to insert using CLI and look for messages. PS. Use DISTINCT instead GROUP BY.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I deleted the `idx_diff_sets_value` index. The file size of that table shrunk from about 32 GiB to 13 GiB. After that, the query ran as expected. I think it was some kind of memory issue. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This may run faster:

```
 INSERT INTO diff_set_values(value)
    select DISTINCT value 
    from diff_sets;
```

Either would run faster if `diff_set_values` had `INDEX(value)`.  However, adding the index would take a long time.

Increase the timeout.

Comment: I already tried `distinct` instead of `group by`. I think I had some memory issues. After deleting the index in the source table, the file size shrunk by 20 GiB and I was able to run the query. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Dorian - That could indicate a different problem -- and the slowness will return after you add a bunch of data.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?